# Getting old props in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am using React (v : 15.4.2) , issue is :
i have page A and B having component ABC in both page A and B .
The props passed to ABC from the page A and B are different .
But when i transition from A to B page and when a callback event is fired which is listened in ABC , it has old prop value (passed from page A).

Component ABC looks like this :

```
class ABC extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        height: 0,
        width: 0
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    windowStore.addOnAppReSizedListener(this._onResize.bind(this));
    this._onResize();

}
componentWillUnmount() {
    windowStore.removeOnAppReSizedListener(this._onResize.bind(this));
}

_onResize() {
    let parentNode = document.getElementById(this.props.id).parentNode.getClientRects()[0];
    this.setState({
        height: parentNode.height,
        width: parentNode.width
    });
}
//i am getting this.props.id of the previous page (A)  
 the actual error it throws is : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null**
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here:
let count=0;
class ABC extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.isLoading = false;

    this.state = {
        id: ++Count 
        height: 0,
        width: 0
    };
}

Comment: sorry for the typo, it is let count=0 ; and not Count.

Answer (score 0):

I presume your that id is a number. Problem is you're not actually setting the property id of state anywhere? Not sure what you're trying to do with the ++Count as I dont see you actually declaring it anywhere nor should set your state properties in this way.

```
class ABC extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        height: 0,
        width: 0
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    windowStore.addOnAppReSizedListener(this._onResize.bind(this));
    this._onResize();

}
componentWillUnmount() {
    windowStore.removeOnAppReSizedListener(this._onResize.bind(this));
}

_onResize() {
    let parentNode = document.getElementById(this.props.id).parentNode.getClientRects()[0];
    this.setState({
        height: parentNode.height,
        width: parentNode.width
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using React-Router for routing? How are you calling your components?

<Route path='/a' id={myAId} component={A} />
<Route path='/b' id={myBId} component={B} />

Comment: I am getting error in line "let parentNode = document.getElementById(this.props.id).parentNode.getClientRects()[0];". "document.getElementById(this.props.id)" is not able to find DOM object, as "this.props.id" value is old (passed from page A).

Comment: my render of Page A & B is as below:
`render() {
  const ID = "ABD_PAGE_B";
 
  let data= this.state.data? this.state.data.Items : [];
  return (
   
                         <ABC
     id={ID}
     prefix={HEADER_PREFIX}
     data={data}
     getData={this._getData.bind(this)}
          />

  );
 }`